# Adding namespace prefix when transforming regular XML into Dublin Core XML

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I may very well be missing something obvious, but I'm not clear on how to code my XSLT stylesheet to transform one "regular" XML file to generate a Dublin Core XML file that includes the namespace "dc" prefix on each element. I've looked through a lot of other answers here and can't seem to figure out how to do this. (I'm using msxsl.exe for the transformation.)

For example, I'm trying to turn this line from my original XML document:

```
    <title>Message received clairaudiently by Mrs. Begg at Lake Pleasant, Fri. March 9, 1945.</title>
```

...into this (after running it through the XSLT transformation):

```
<dc:title>Message received clairaudiently by Mrs. Begg at Lake Pleasant, Fri. March 9, 1945.</dc:title>
```

Here's the stylesheet element I'm using in my XSL file:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://:www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

So my question is, do I have to hard-code the "dc:" prefix into the individual elements in the XSL stylesheet, a la:

```
<dc:title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></dc:title>
```

Or is there a way to have the XSL transformation add the prefix to each element automatically?

Comment: So, the only change you'd like to make is prefixing _all_ elements with `dc:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [I]s there a way to have the XSL transformation add the prefix to each element automatically?

If you want to prefix all elements without exceptions, you don't have to do it manually. For example, if you have an input file like:

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item/>
    <item/>
</root>
```

apply the following transformation. The stylesheet does not change anything except prefixing all elements with `dc:`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:element name="{concat('dc:',name())}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dc:root xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
   <dc:item/>
   <dc:item/>
</dc:root>
```

Note that it is impossible to tell whether this can be integrated into your current stylsheet. Unfortunately, you did not reveal much of it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! In a way it does answer my question - that solution seems much more complex than I would have expected for this assignment. I'm trying to validate my result XML file against a very simple DC RNG. I'll get back to it and see what I can do, and if I have more questions I'll re-post the entire code here. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3415610 You are welcome. If you have another question it would be best to open a new question, if I understood correctly. Please consider accepting the answer (mark the tick on the left) if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit embarrassed to say that in the end, it turned out I didn't even need the prefix. The reason the DC XML file wasn't validating was because the RNG I was validating it against required a specific element order, which I wasn't using. The error messages I was getting from Jing were so cryptic it took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: @user3415610 No worries, you're welcome. But next time you could include cryptic error messages right away. It's always better to start with the problem you are facing than with your attempted solution - and there are some clever people in the XML corner here who would help you figure it out.